# Turn Hover Event back on after disabling on Click?

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover, mouseleave

I have a rating script that will highlight list items based on where you are hovered on the list. On click I disable the hover events to ensure the list items highlighted stay highlighted. I will then run an ajax call that will save the rating for the specific item. I would then like the hover events to turn back on. Any suggestions? Here is the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/defmetalhead/n76My/1/

```
   <ul class="beeRating">
      <li class="oneBee" id="1">1</li>
      <li class="twoBee" id="2">2</li>
      <li class="threeBee" id="3">3</li>
      <li class="fourBee" id="4">4</li>
      <li class="fiveBee" id="5">5</li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/127/Jquery-simple-rating-system-with-star

Comment: yea many different ways to do this, you can simply add a class to the container when clicked and remove the class when needed. In the hover functions, check if the container has that class, if it does not, do hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n76My/5/)**

Try this I have edited your code,It works

```
var index=1;
$(".beeRating li").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        if(index==1)
        {
        $(this).addClass('stop');
        $("li").each(function(index,domEle) {
            $(domEle).css('opacity', '1');
            if( $(this).hasClass('stop') ) {
                return false;
            }
        })
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
         if(index==1)
        {
        $(this).removeClass('stop');
        $("li").each(function(index,domEle) {
            $(domEle).css('opacity', '.25');
        })
        }
    },
    click: function() {
        var rating = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(rating);
        index=0;

        $.ajax({    //call the function to do ajax request or do it here itself
           url: "<your url>"

           }).done(function() {   // important !! on done set the index as 1
              alert("success");
              index=1;  
            });
       }
});
```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Comment: this answer is pretty close. I will accept this one as an answer. However, once clicked, you must hover over all highlighted items before you can set a new rating. I am not too concerned about it though. The script will reset on load.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var $ratings = $(".beeRating li");

function onMouseOver(obj){
    obj.addClass('stop');
    $("li").each(function(index,domEle) {
        $(domEle).css('opacity', '1');
        if( $(this).hasClass('stop') ) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}

function onMouseLeave(obj){    
    obj.removeClass('stop');
    $("li").each(function(index,domEle) {
        $(domEle).css('opacity', '.25');
    });
}

function onClick(obj){
    var rating = obj.attr('id');    
    console.log(rating);
    $("li").each(function(index,domEle) {
        $(this).removeClass('stop');
        $(this).off('mouseover mouseleave');
    })
}

function rebindEvents(){
    $ratings
        .off('click mouseover mouseleave')
        .on({
        mouseover: function() {
            onMouseOver($(this));
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            onMouseLeave($(this));
        },
        click: function() {
            onClick($(this));
            //send ajax call here or show some delay and rebind all events again
            rebindEvents();
        }
   });
}

rebindEvents();
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n76My/3/

I hope it helps.

Comment: maverickosama92 thanks for the effort, however the list does not stay highlighted once clicked